# Efficiently load chat log

Tags: javascript, chat, fetching-strategy

```
/user/:userId
```

```
user = {
    user_id
    username
    name
    email
    pfpsrc
};
```

```
/chatlog
```

```
{
   responce: [
      {
         message_id
         message
         message_date
         user_id
      },
      {
         message_id
         message
         message_date
         user_id
      }
   ]
}
```

When appending messages from `/chatlog` to the DOM, how can I grab user data from `/user` for every message in chatlog efficiently?

My current code fetches `/user/:userId` for every message in chatlog which is inefficient and slow af

Comment: Why not just cache the users you already fetched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this for more efficency, your Back-end should return the needed user data on `/chatlog` response.

The changes api will return

```js
{
   response: [
      {
         message_id
         message
         message_date
         user: {
            user_id
            username
            name
            email
            pfpsrc
        },
      {
         message_id
         message
         message_date
         user: {
            user_id
            username
            name
            email
            pfpsrc
          }
        ]
}
```

With that you can use user that returned.

Comment: How is transmitting twice the amount of data more efficient?

Comment: There also fetching the needed user data in ```/chatlog``` and caching it. But if consider the HTTP connection time, it may not worth it. So the answer can become what to optimize.  
My answer is just the simplist way to improve HTTP connection and fetching time. Not considering size.